# Importing gmail contacts using GoogleAuthUtil

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-services

I'm trying to add import contacts from gmail account function in my android app. So the first problem is to get access token from gmail. I've found that there is `GoogleAuthUtil` class which can help me with it. 
Here is my code:

```
private void importContactsFromGmail() {
    showProgressDialog();
    GetTokenTask getTokenTask = new GetTokenTask();
    getTokenTask.execute();
    String token = "";
    try {
        token = getTokenTask.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(token);
    hideProgressDialog();
}

private class GetTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String token = "";
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, <My_gmail_account>, "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Now after calling `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken` my app completely freezes(no errors in Logcat). I completely stuck and I need your help. 
What is wrong with my code? Maybe I should import contacts in some other way?

Comment: What device are you running on?

Comment: Bersh, Can you please send me the source to fetch the gmail contacts in android? I need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is related but calling the `.get()` method on the main thread is not correct because is blocking method.

What if you use the `AsyncTask` in this way?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new GetTokenTask().execute();
    }

    static class GetTokenTask  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            String token = "";
            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, <My_gmail_account>, "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

(I wrote without compiling it, maybe it needs to be adjusted)

Answer (score 0):

On Android devices, Gmail contacts are synced locally onto the device and are available via a public [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html), therefore there's no reason you'd need to use the Google API to pull what is already available. There is a whole [training series](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html) dedicated specifically to retrieving a list of contacts.

Note that the Contacts training series does assume you have knowledge of Content Providers already, so it may be helpful to read up on [the basics of Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) as well.

Comment: Yes, but user can disable sync for some reason. In this case I'd like to give user possibility to import contacts from gmail avoiding syncing it with phone